# How to Inject multiple generic Interface dependencies using dot net core IService collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

We have a following hierarchy

```
public class ProviderResponse
{
    public string Prop {get; set;}
}

public class Provider1Response: ProviderResponse
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
}
public class Provider2Response: ProviderResponse
{
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

Here ProviderResponse is base class containing common properties and there are several other extensions to it.

Then we have Logic classes

```
public interface IProviderResponseLogic<T> where T:ProviderResponse
{
   bool Process<T>(T t);
}

public class Provider1ResponseLogic : IProviderResponseLogic<Provider1Response>
{
    public bool Process(Provider1Response resp)
    {
        //logic
    }
}

public class Provider2ResponseLogic : IProviderResponseLogic<Provider2Response>
{
    public bool Process(Provider2Response resp)
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

I need to conditionally inject the specific implementation of logic in the controller class. In my Action method, I have an input param enum (Provider) that will decide which concrete logic to call.

I have tried factory method injection by creating `Func<Provider, IProviderResponseLogic<T>` like this

```
services.AddTransient<Provider1ResponseLogic>();
services.AddTransient<Provider2ResponseLogic>();
services.AddTransient<Func<Provider, IProviderResponseLogic<ProviderResponse>>>(serviceProvider => key =>
             {
                 return key switch
                 {
                     Provider.Provider1 => serviceProvider.GetService<Provider1ResponseLogic>()
                     Provider.Provider2 => serviceProvider.GetService<Provider2ResponseLogic>()
                     _ => null,//key not found
                 };
             });
```

It is giving the below error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Provider1ResponseLogic' to 'IProviderResponseLogic<ProviderResponse>'
```

Basically, it is not returning a more derived type.

What is wrong here and how can I correct it?

I can also register each implementation with the interface like `services.AddTransient<IProviderResponseLogic<Provider1ResponseLogic>, Provider1ResponseLogic>();`
and inject each one in the controller, but I think if this will go out of control if the implementation classes increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `Provider1Response` inherits from `ProviderResponse`, that doesn't mean `IProviderResponseLogic<Provider1Response>` can be converted to `IProviderResponseLogic<ProviderResponse>`. This conversion can only happen if the type parameter of the base interface is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). But that does not appear to be an appropriate solution to your problem, because you're intending to use the type parameter `T` in a contravariant position.

> I can also register each implementation with the interface [...] and inject each one in the controller, but I think if this will go out of control if the implementation classes increases.

I think this is the only good solution. A switch case would also "go out of control" when you're adding more implementations.